# Is Hibernate also use connection pool as JDBC?

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, jboss7.x, connection-pooling

I use JBOSS 7.1 web server for my application. I configured JBOSS connection pool and use it for JDBC connections. I also use hibernate in my application. And i want to know if hibernate also use this connection pool or me need to configure other connection pool(for example c3p0) for hibernate?

Comment: If you are using JNDI to configure Hibernate then Yes it will use Jboss connection pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:schema</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.default_schema">schema</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>

  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
```

```
hibernate.c3p0.min_size – Minimum number of JDBC connections in the pool. Hibernate default: 1
hibernate.c3p0.max_size – Maximum number of JDBC connections in the pool. Hibernate default: 100
hibernate.c3p0.timeout – When an idle connection is removed from the pool (in second). Hibernate default: 0, never expire.
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements – Number of prepared statements will be cached. Increase performance. Hibernate default: 0 , caching is disable.
hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period – idle time in seconds before a connection is automatically validated. Hibernate default: 0
```

more detail refer [link](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowToConfigureTheC3P0ConnectionPool)

Answer (score 1):

**C3P0 Connection Pool**

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
```

`hibernate.c3p0.min_size`:

- *Minimum number of JDBC connections in the pool.*
- **Hibernate default**: 1

`hibernate.c3p0.max_size`:

- *Maximum number of JDBC connections in the pool.*
- **Hibernate default**: 100

`hibernate.c3p0.timeout`:

- *When an idle connection is removed from the pool (in second).*
- **Hibernate default**: 0, *never expire.*

`hibernate.c3p0.max_statements`:

- *Number of prepared statements will be cached. Increase performance.*
- **Hibernate default**: 0, *caching is disable.*

`hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period`:

- *idle time in seconds before a connection is automatically validated.*
- **Hibernate default**: 0

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch01.html